# Show that $\int_{0}^{x} \frac{\sin \theta}{\theta}\,d\theta = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)(2n+1)!}.$

Tags: integration

Does anybody have the idea how to prove this?

> 1. Show that 
>      $$\int_{0}^{x} \frac{\sin \theta}{\theta}\,d\theta = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)(2n+1)!}.$$

This exercise is from here: [Music: A Mathematical Offering](https://homepages.abdn.ac.uk/mth192/pages/html/music.pdf), page 46, exercise 1. I will be very thank full for any information

Comment: Please use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Express $\sin(\theta)$ as a MacLaurin series. Then integrate the integrand term-by-term.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: $\sin(\theta)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n\theta^{2n+1}}{(2k+1)!}$ and the partial sums converge uniformly, so you may interchange summation and integration

Comment: Thomas Grubb, thank you a lot!